# Adding google services - Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to Implement GCM Client in Android Studio following the steps on this website: 
[Implementing GCM Client on Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client)

As mentioned under "Set Up Google Play Services" I edited my application's build.gradle file so that it looks like that:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.buuurn.gymio"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.+'
}
```

If I sync gradle now I get this error message:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Applications/adt-bundle 23/sdk/build-tools/23.0.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I've already tried to change

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.+'
```

to i.e.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```

but the same error has occurred.

I've also read some posts about gradle errors while adding google services but nothing has helped yet.

Thank you!

Comment: build tools version is `23` not `23.0.0` and its in single quotes `'23'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to check your "buildToolsVersion"? If not, go to setting->app->properties->check your build version to see if you find it, if not use the max version you have or update it.

Regarding this error:"finished with non-zero exit value 1" there are several reason, if it caused by RAM, try restart your device, if it caused by your java environment, maybe you should reinstall.

Comment: You are a hero :-D. I read about the build tool mistake, but I didn't found my version - fixed it, now it syncs perfectly! Thank you!