# Error: Execution failed for task ': app: processDebugGoogleServices

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, build.gradle

I have a bug in Android Studio.
New activity blank application, I add "build.gradle (project)"

```
 dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha9'
     classpath 'com.google.gms: google-services: 2.0.0-alpha9'
 }
```

And in "build.gradle (app)"

```
dependencies {
     compile FileTree (dir: 'libs', include: ['* .jar'])
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
     compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'

     // Dependency for Google Sign-In
     compile 'com.google.android.gms: play-auth-services: 8.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Compile, and the error is:

> "Error: Execution failed for task ': app: processDebugGoogleServices'.
>    Com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected name at line 28, column 20 "

I reinstalled Android Studio, SDK, and always the same, any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32212623/adding-google-services-execution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebugresources

Comment: Estás equivocado, revisa bien, el error lo puedes replicar fácilmente al crear un nuevo proyecto con actividad en blanco, agregar el classpath y apply plugin; compilas y error.

Comment: I managed the operation of Google SignIn removing "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'' I do not know what consequences have but so far get user data. Regards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you are doing Google Sign-in in your app.
The `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` statement would try to parse your `google-services.json` file (normally located  in the app folder)
Open that file and look for any malformed JSON at line 28.
(Possibly copy/paste it into an [online JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com/)).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the editor use to modify the 'google-services.json' also will cause the issue. I use OS X TextEdit to edit, the issue happened, but after I use UltraEdit, the issue is solved. I think maybe the file coding issue.