# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I am new in `react native` and I use it in Ubuntu. I would like to run a project on my PC. I use yarn and android emulator. Here is my installed application versions:

```
yarn: 1.2.0

nmp: 3.10.10
```

I got the following error while use:

```
$ react-native run-android
```

Here is the error:

```
  * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
    > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

I have tested many solutions that exist in `stackoverflow` but, non of them did't work for me.  such as:

[Adding google services - Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32212623/adding-google-services-execution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebugresources)

[Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497882/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug-in-androi)

I also use `Google play service` and I have installed `Firebase` plugin. 
Do you have idea that what should I do?

Comment: Can you share your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: @wizloc: Thanks for your reply. Where can I find it in my project? Is it in current path of the project? I could't find it! I should mention that the project was completely worked in the other PC!

Comment: android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml. Specifically I'm just curious what the `android:minSdkVersion` field value is. My guess is 16?

Comment: @wizloc: Yes you are right! it is 16! <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>

Comment: @wizloc: Could you guess the problem? :)

Comment: Show me your `Build.gradle`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My guess is you are over the 64k reference limit and need to enable multidexing. The second article you linked referenced how to solve this, but many react-native projects are initialized with minSdkVersion of 16, so there is an extra step to enabled multidex. You have two options.

**Option 1:**

Upgrade your minSdkVersion to 21 in your AndroidManifest.xml file (android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) and also your build.gradle file (android/app/build.gradle), then in your build.gradle file add multiDexEnabled to true in this line

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```

**Option 2:**

If you need to stay at minSdkVersion 16, set multiDexEnabled to true in your build.gradle file, then add this line under "dependencies" in the same file

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
  ...(your other dependencies here)
}
```

Then depending on whether you override the Application class, perform one of the following:

If you do not override the Application class, edit your manifest file to set android:name in the  tag as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If you do override the Application class in android/app/src/main/java/MainApplication.java, change it to extend MultiDexApplication (if possible) as follows:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
```

Here is android's documentation on what this error means and why it occurs, as well as how to fix it https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, it gave me the same error. :(

Comment: If you can copy and paste your android/app/build.gradle file, I can take another look

Comment: with mixing your answer and one of the anwser above, finally I could fix it. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Mine minSdkVersion was at 19 and a I had to upgrade it to 21 as well and that fix my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me, when you're inside your project directory try using:

```
cd android && gradlew clean
cd .. && react-native run-android
```

Source: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10367#issuecomment-308153481

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting this error by generating the Release app then you can follow this answer :-https://stackoverflow.com/a/57548822/9444013

Answer (score 0):

after 2 hours of searching this Solution works for me!
cmd cd android
then ./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace