# ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont (React Native)

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

Upon building my project in react native I get the following error:

```
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /Users/jackson/projects/scratch/repo-name/android/app/google-services.json

> Task :app:generateBundledResourcesHashDebug
4f53cda18c2baa0c0354bb5f9a3ecbe5ed12ab4d8e11ba873c2f11161202b945

ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontVariationSettings
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:ttcIndex


> Task :app:processDebugResources
Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process /Users/jackson/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I /Users/jackson/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar -M /Users/jackson/projects/scratch/repo-name/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/jackson/projects/scratch/repo-name/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug -m -J /Users/jackson/projects/scratch/repo-name/android/app/build/generated/source/r/debug -F /Users/jackson/projects/scratch/repo-name/android/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/resources-debug.ap_ -D /Users/jackson/projects/scratch/repo-name/android/app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/debug/manifest_keep.txt --custom-package com.project -0 apk --output-text-symbols /Users/jackson/projects/scratch/repo-name/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug --no-version-vectors}
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
        ... 41 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process /Users/jackson/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I /Users/jackson/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar -M /Users/jackson/projects/scratch/repo-name/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/jackson/projects/scratch/repo-name/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug -m -J /Users/jackson/projects/scratch/repo-name/android/app/build/generated/source/r/debug -F /Users/jackson/projects/scratch/repo-name/android/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/resources-debug.ap_ -D /Users/jackson/projects/scratch/repo-name/android/app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/debug/manifest_keep.txt --custom-package com.project -0 apk --output-text-symbols /Users/jackson/projects/scratch/repo-name/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug --no-version-vectors}
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:73)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:48)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:78)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:74)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1237)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:911)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:822)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:664)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:48)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessExecutor$1.run(GradleProcessExecutor.java:58)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/jackson/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:380)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:46)
        ... 9 more


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
129 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 121 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

I've tried following the advice of the following with no avail.

- [This one doesn't exactly apply because my project doesn't use background geolocation. But I did add `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.+'` to my build.gradle but that didn't have any effect.](https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/issues/116#issuecomment-340258780)
- [This one doesn't describe a react native project, but perhaps the suggested modifications to build.gradle would work. They did not.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49173386)

After some modification I was able to produce this different error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/me/projects/myproject/android/app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/debug/componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [/Users/me/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-core-ui-27.0.2.aar/5533dcabe97ba965687ff41b9cf1591c/jars/classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/v4/view/ViewPager$1.class]))
```

[And this was not helpful either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46774530/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug-in-react-native)

I've also tried running `gradlew clean`

Also as a side note, it seems as if my Android build is very fragile. Almost every other week I'm having to go down another rabbit hole to fix some dependency issue. Has anyone found a good way to stabilize everything?

Here is build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
            }
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 24
        versionName "1.2.9"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            // Note: CodePush updates should not be tested in Debug mode as they are overriden by the RN packager. However, because CodePush checks for updates in all modes, we must supply a key.
            buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", '""'
        }
        releaseStaging {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", '"1psOppiGxP0-cJpCePhMqgEjeO4l2533309f-9929-415c-8999-d7fda42c3857"'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", '"0wPxPhihmtxxEdma3mU4zIGIFNdi2533309f-9929-415c-8999-d7fda42c3857"'
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-code-push')
    compile (project(':react-native-code-push')) {
        exclude(group: 'android.arch.core')
    }
    compile project(':react-native-config')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-radar')
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
    compile project(':react-native-photo-view')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-fcm')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile(project(':react-native-fbsdk')){
        exclude(group: 'com.facebook.android', module: 'facebook-android-sdk')
    }
    compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
      transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Make sure you have the matching version of compileSdkVersion and your libraries - for example: compileSdkVersion 27 and api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'

Comment: I've updated the post to include my build.gradles I have a matching sdk version and api.

Answer (score 0):

Upon more experimentation I found that the problem was with the react-native-radar package. I opened an issue here: https://github.com/radarlabs/react-native-radar/issues/15, so if you want updates you can check there.

Edit: This issue contains the solution: https://github.com/radarlabs/react-native-radar/issues/14#issuecomment-374576648